# Ultracoproducts and Cartesian products

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, lo.logic, set-theory, gn.general-topology

Let $X$ be a metrizable compact topological space, let $\mathcal U$ be an ultrafilter, and denote by $X^{\mathcal U}$ the ultracopower of $X$ with respect to $\mathcal U$.
As a C$^*$-algebraist, I prefer to define $X^{\mathcal U}$ as the compact Hausdorff space satisfying
\begin{align*}
C(X^{\mathcal U},\mathbb C) &\cong \prod_{\mathcal U} C(X,\mathbb C) \\
&:= \ell^\infty(\mathbb N, C(X, \mathbb C))/\{(f_n)_n \mid \lim_{n\to\mathcal U} \|f_n\|_{\infty} = 0\}.
\end{align*}
It can alternatively be described, directly, as ultrafilters in $\mathbb N \times X$ which respect $\mathcal U$ (see Bankston's "Reduced
coproducts of compact Hausdorff spaces" for a more precise version of this).

My question is: if $Y$ is another metrizable compact topological space, is it the case that $(X \times Y)^{\mathcal U} \cong X^{\mathcal U} \times Y^{\mathcal U}$?
Equivalently, in terms of C$^*$-algebras, is it the case that
$$ \prod_{\mathcal U} C(X \times Y, \mathbb C) \cong \left(\prod_{\mathcal U}C(X, \mathbb C)\right) \otimes \left(\prod_{\mathcal U} C(Y, \mathbb C)\right)? $$

My intuition, looking at the C$^*$-algebra version, is that this isn't true, although I've found it difficult to prove this.

(Note: we could do an ultracoproduct with respect to a sequence of spaces instead, but this is notationally messier and, well, let's first see the answer to the question I stated before going there.)

Comment: Anything in the Ge-Hadwin paper?

Comment: You might want to clarify for the non-FA readers that your direct product is (I assume) the one in the Banach space category, i.e. bounded sequences and not all sequences, and that your tensor product is a completion of the algebraic tensor product :)

Comment: Yemon: No, nothing in this direction seems to be addressed in the Ge-Hadwin paper. And thank you for your second comment; changes have been made.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aaron, the answer is big **no** if $X$ and $Y$ are infinite (no metrasibility assumptions required to show that the answer is always negative).

Indeed, $C((X\times Y)^{\mathcal{U}})$ is a [Grothendieck space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_space) as an ultraproduct of $\mathscr{L}_\infty$-spaces over a countably incomplete ultrafilter. (See Propositon 3.2 [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.4387v1.pdf).) On the other hand $$C(X^{\mathcal{U}}\times Y^{\mathcal{U}})\cong C(X^{\mathcal{U}})\otimes C(Y^{\mathcal{U}})\cong C(X^{\mathcal{U}}, C(Y^{\mathcal{U}})) $$ contains a complemented (Banach-space) copy of $c_0$ by the main result of

> P. Cembranos, [$C(K, E)$ contains a complemented copy of $c_0$](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1984-091-04/S0002-9939-1984-0746089-2/S0002-9939-1984-0746089-2.pdf), *Proc. Amer. Math. Soc.* **91** (1984), 556-558

so it is manifestly not Grothendieck. The conclusion is that $C((X\times Y)^{\mathcal{U}})$ and $C(X^{\mathcal{U}}\times X^{\mathcal{U}})$ are not even Banach-space isomorphic.

*Remark*. [One can tweak Cembranos' proof](https://academic.oup.com/qjmath/article-abstract/66/4/1063/2362453?redirectedFrom=fulltext) to obtain the following result:

> If $A$ is a C*-algebra, $E$ is a Banach space (both $A$ and $E$ are infinite dimensional) and $\gamma$ is any Banach-space tensor cross-norm on $A\odot E$, then $A\otimes_\gamma E$ is not a Grothendieck space.

As a corollary to this one obtains a negative answer to Simon Wasserman's quesiton whether the Calkin algebra can be written as a non-trivial tensor product of two C*-algebras. I might write this down at some point.

Comment: Thanks Tomek, this is quite insightful for me. I've asked a follow-up question here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/179257/ultracoproducts-of-cx-algebras

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to see that the answer is no for infinite $X$ and $Y$, from a more model-theoretic point of view.  As an ultrapower over a countably incomplete ultrafilter, $C(X\times Y)^{\mathcal{U}}$ is countably saturated.  It follows from this (actually, from the weaker property of countable degree-$1$ saturation) that $C(X \times Y)^{\mathcal{U}}$ is $SAW^*$ (see [Farah and Hart, "Countable saturation of corona algebras"](http://www.math.yorku.ca/~ifarah/Ftp/farahC0002_farahC0002.pdf)), and hence cannot be the tensor product of two infinite-dimensional algebras (see [Saeed Ghasemi, "$SAW^*$-algebras are essentially non-factorizable](http://arxiv.org/abs/1209.3459)).

Comment: Just to complement your answer, my remark actually covers Ghasemi's result as SAW*-algebras are Grothendieck. However, one can easily prove that $K=(X\times Y)^U$ is an F-space in which case $C(K)$ is a Grothendieck space; in other words no C*-machinery is required here.